# SSIS Cozyroc Dynamics GP Tools, using ObjectCriteriaXML Scope of ReturnBasedonCustomerId returns error

Tags: ssis, dynamics-gp

I'm in the middle of evaluating the Cozyroc Dynamics GP tools. I'm very comfortable using SSIS and have used Scribe in the past to integrate to Dynamics but I'd prefer to use SSIS on this project. I have managed to get simple queries to work without a problem but I'm having problems when I try using the ObjectCriteriaXML.

For example, I can query the GP Customer object and get back all of the Customer, Customer Extension, Customer Address and Customer Address Extension data when the ObjectCriteriaXML Scope has the default value of "ReturnAll". However, when I edit the ObjectCriteriaXML criteria and change the Scope to "ReturnBasedonCustomerId" I get nothing but errors whether I add a filter on ID or not.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Insufficient
>   authorization to perform this action.

The login I'm using currently has the Dynamics GP Web Services role of "Superuser" and it works for "ReturnAll" so I don't think it's an issue of permissions but I'm not a GP expert by any stretch.

I'm assuming that I'm making a simple mistake somewhere but I haven't been able to find any documentation or blogs on using the Cozyroc Dynamics GP tools.

Any pointers to sources of info or suggestions on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My bad, after I RTFM for GP Web Services I see that the "ReturnBasedonCustomerId" criteria uses the customer ID associated with the current user and my user ID wasn't associated with a specific customer.

That being said, I'm still having issues when using "ReturnAll" with a filter on customer ID, it returns all of the customers rather than the one I'm filtering on. SoapUI returns just one customer when I call the service directly so it must be something in what I'm doing in SSIS.

Any insights or pointers to blogs or documentation would still be very much appreciated.

Thank you